# Can't remove background color from one li item

Tags: css, background, html-lists

The website is http://vs.avischulman.com/

Right now I'm trying to remove the golden background and border from the last link in the menu. (right side) it's a cart. and the background is preventing it from being visible.

I tried

```
#top-cart {
background:none!important;
}
```

I also tried selecting with li#top-cart, #header #navigation ul.nav > li a:nth-child(4) and a few more with no avail.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to target this rule :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
#header #navigation ul.nav > li:last-of-type a { ... } }
```

Use `last-of-type` to target the last li element ,

and you will be able to style the last element on the menu , and so on for the other screen resolutions ...

Comment: Just did. :) had to wait a few minutes before it would let me.